# What are the practical consequences of SD card DRM?

Tags: file, storage, flash-memory

I've just read that SD cards all have some DRM code that will prevent reads or writes of "protected content".

As my code will sometimes use SD cards for storage, what is the practical consequence of the DRM? What steps (if any) do I need to take to avoid writing out files that might not be read back?

Comment: The "secure" part is (as far as I know) just the globally unique ID of each SD card. So an application can verify that the data and the SD card "belong together" e.g. an digital map which should not be copied to another SD card. Unless you actively read the unique ID of the card, you should not have to worry about it.

Comment: The unique ID is not in "secure" part but in well known CID structure. There is other really "secret" storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so simple. DRM functions use separate storage from non-protected area. There are special SD commands for DRM and in addition, there is "secret" part of SD Card spec. Buy membership for $1000 at sdcard.org and get the info :) In short - DRM features can be used mostly by special hardware (microcontroller connected to SD slot), not simple PC software.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, if I use only normal file I/O operations, I don't ever have to worry about writing a magic bit pattern that can't be read back?

Comment: Don't worry and write what is necessary to file.

Comment: Or you can just google "part 3 security specification" and read it for free—companies are always accidentally leaking it on the Internet despite all the "confidential" notices and watermarks.